# Noise generator or sweep genetor instead of tracking generator

Tags: oscillator, spectrum-analyzer

My spectrum analyzer tek 492 does not have a tracking generator. I have HP8350B in my eyes (to buy) but can be sweep oscillator used instead of tracking generator? So far i understand TG is at the same frequency as LO when SA perform sweeping. I will need to synchronise somehow sweep of SA and HP8350B. Is that possible? Thanks